# Matlab - Unknown Warning and implay default size window

Tags: matlab, function, warnings

Hi guys i got a question on a project i have on matlab and since i am new i need your assist :

1. I have a function that works great, but i am getting a warning :
   `"Warning: Size vector should be a row vector with integer elements."`
   and the code where i am getting the warning is:
   `Vector = zeros(2,x1*x2/size^2);` 
   i 've seen some other posts that talk about this, but there is no solution mentioned.

Comment: Hi. It'll be easier for people to help you if you provide the code that is breaking. Just the relevant parts. Also - it's much better to break your questions into two separate questions, rather than squish them into one. That way they can be answered separately. I'd recommend leaving #1 here and breaking out #2 into a separate question. :)

Comment: oh ok i am gona edit it then  as you said :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `x1*x2/size^2` is probably not an integer, you should `round`, `floor` or `ceil` it.

Comment: hey mate, i did use round function but the warning did not dissapear

Comment: @Try_me34 How did you use the `round` function?

Comment: oh sorry mate you were right, i did use round on zeros(2,x1*x2/size^2), but when i use round on x1*x2/size^2 the warning dissapears, huge thanks!